# Scala Worksheet issues with values and output

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin

Finding quite a big error on the Scala worksheet whilst in Eclipse 3.7.2 downloaded fromTypesafe for a Linux, Ubuntu

Seem to get issues when defining values - something which doesn't happen on my course teachers screen.

Please see as follows:

```
 package week3

 object rational2 {
   val x = new Rational(1,2)           //> x  : week3.Rational = week3.Rational@1e9cb75
   x.num                               //> res0: Int = 1
   x.den                               //> res1: Int = 2
   val y = new Rational(2,3)           //> y  : week3.Rational = week3.Rational@1786e64

   x.addRationals(y)                   //> res2: week3.Rational = week3.Rational@197a37c
  val z = new Rational(3,2)            //> z  : week3.Rational = week3.Rational@6e3d60
```

As you can see it doesn't even tell me what x, y, z are but points to a variable defined as the being within the package. 
Previously had a known issue of highlighting errors when there wasn't one, but had to reinstall Eclipse to get rid of these.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: please note a Rational class has been defined, beneath the object one - I simply didn't paste it as it doesn't show any errors and isn't dealt with by the interactive worksheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is the `toString` representation of the `Rational` class. You haven't defined one so it just goes with the default.

You're probably meant to define `Rational` as a `case class`, which will give you a sensible `toString` representation automatically.

Comment: please see Edit - it has been defined in the worksheet itself, just not here as does not highlight error issue

Comment: I mean you haven't defined a `toString` method for that class.